# Add 3D model from Blender (or similar) inside a 3D scatter

Tags: javascript, 3d, plotly, plotly.js

I have a 3D scatter plot, and I would like to add a 3D model inside of this. Creating an object from "mesh3d" is not really doable, basic polygons are fine, but detailed models are not going to happen.

I want something simple, but below should give an idea of what im talking about. Is plotly the wrong tool for the job? (i'm assuming yes), if so, what shall I use? This is going onto a React app, so will need to be JS based. If I can use Plotly, great, but how?

Thanks in advance.

Edit, example plot of a cube;

```
const cube = {
            x: [0, buildingWidth, 0, buildingWidth, 0, buildingWidth, 0, buildingWidth],
            y: [0, 0, buildingWidth, buildingWidth, 0, 0, buildingWidth, buildingWidth],
            z: [0, 0, 0, 0, buildingHeight, buildingHeight, buildingHeight, buildingHeight],
            i: [0, 3, 4, 7, 0, 6, 1, 7, 0, 5, 2, 7],
            j: [1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 1, 6, 3],
            k: [3, 0, 7, 4, 6, 0, 7, 1, 5, 0, 7, 2],
            flatshading: true,
            lighting: {
                facenormalsepsilon: 0,
            },
            lightposition: {
                x: 2000,
                y: 1000,
            },
            color: "rgb(116,115,115)",
            opacity: 0.2,
            type: "mesh3d",
            name: "cube",
            hoverinfo: "skip",
        };
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Your question is a bit general and might be closed as `opinion based` or `asking for specific recommendations for libraries` but i think `plotly.js` could possibly do the job. in plotly-python there are definitely different types of complex 3d surfaces that can be displayed. some more details in your question or relevant code will help. also what is the format of the data for the 3d model going to be?

Comment: @DerekO thanks for the reply. I have edited the question. I am using plotly.js. 

Basically adding a complete shape is a none starter, unless a 3d app like blender could output a set of coords for me.